# How do I make a love story, that isn't cliche but different from others?

Tags: fan-fiction, cliches

Okay, so I just wanted to know what is the less cliche way of making a romantic fanfiction.

I know this question is short, but I just want to know.

Comment: Just a heads-up: based on my personal experience, people who actively read romance usually *like* those common cliches, so there's nothing wrong with using them.

Comment: Hi Laura. It seems that your question is too broad and opinion-based for this site. Perhaps you can edit the question to improve it. E.g., you could suggest different options and ask which is the least cliche, or anything else that would make the question more specific and objective. This would help somebody to potentially answer your question.

Comment: @hb20007 Hey dude, yes I saw your comment and dw, I followed what you said. Edited the question and re-fixed it, based off what you said. Thank you btw for your help because this is my first time asking on here.

Comment: @AnnaA.Fitzgerald Well, I read some of the comments and I think so. Yes.